# syntax error: expression expected

Tags: prolog

I'm going through a learn Prolog [tutorial](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse1).  I pulled a single line from the example:

`happy(yolanda).`

and put it into an XGP file.  When I compile it I get:

> syntax error: expression expected

This same line works ok when I load it into [swipl](http://www.swi-prolog.org/) so I guess there's some difference there.

How can I run `happy(yolanda)` and get a Yes that she is happy in [XGP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xgp/)?

Comment: Well, certainly a case of getting things into XGP correctly. If you have a fact stated in a file (`happy(yolanda).`, with the terminating, obligatory period), and then at a query prompt type, `happy(yolanda).` (again, with the period), you should get "yes" or "true". And if you query, `happy(X).` you should get `X = yolanda`. There are some [XGP instructions](http://users.dickinson.edu/~jmac/courses/previous/fall-2013-comp356/resources/xgp-instructions.html) kicking around, and don't know if you've checked them out and if they help...

Comment: Did you saved your code in a `.pl` file? Just tried it. It works fine. No syntax errors.

Comment: Yes it is a .pl file.  Thanks for verifying this should work :)!  I was able to try some other things once I knew that much.

Answer (score 0):

I think there was a bad character that showed up when I copy-pasted the code from the website into the .pl file.  I deleted all the whitespace and the file started to compile.

> happy(yolanda).

Once the file is saved then in the Evaluate Query box you can run `happy(yolanda).` and it will say 'Success' just as @lurker said.

Comment: Ugh, yep, got to be careful about copy/paste from web code samples. I've had issues with that copying from code snippets on SO occasionally as well.